# How to query data without repeats and minimize the time?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

There are 3 entities - `articles`, `journals` and `subscribers`. There are no restrictions on how to store data in database.
The same article can be simultaneously published in several journals.

> How to select all published articles from subscribed journals sorted
>   by date of publication and without repeats?

The easiest way:

1. Create a table with articles:
   **posts**
   `p_id`, `j1_id`, `j2_id`, `text`, `date`
2. Create a table with subscribtions:
   **follows**
   `f_id`, `u_id`, `j_id` (u_id — is a user id from table **users**)
3. Execute:

example query

```
select posts.* from posts inner join follows on (j_id = j1_id or j_id
= j2_id) where u_id = 1 order by date desc
```

This query returns data with duplicates. You can use mechanisms `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`, but it creates an additional sorting operation to remove duplicates.

The other way it can be done using mechanism `UNION`, but it also uses a `DISTINCT`.

```
(select posts.* from posts inner join follows on j_id = j1_id where u_id = 1)
union
(select posts.* from posts inner join follows on j_id = j2_id where u_id = 1)
order by date desc
```

Perhaps I selected the incorrect storage structure in my way.

Actually the question, is it possible to do something about this problem, to minimize the time required for big data?

Comment: can you post sample records?

Comment: I have no sample data, sorry.

Comment: How large are the tables supposed to be?

Comment: Can you please clarify what `j1_id` and `j2.id` are for?  Also is there a reason why you are not creating a table for **journals**?

Comment: Tables contain millions of posts and thousands of journals.

Comment: j1_id and j2_id are ref for j_id. Eg, post 1 is published in journal 1 and 2, so there is a record in the posts: 1, 1, 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following table structure

posts : pid, text, date
journals : jid, jtext
journals_posts : jid, pid
follows : fid, uid, jid

```
select distinct posts.* from posts 
inner join journals_posts on journals_posts.pid = posts.pid 
inner join follows on follows.jid = journals_posts.jid 
where follows.uid = <userid>
```

to take care of speed you can create index on
journals_posts(jid)
follows(uid)

you might required to create indexes on other fields check with "explain " which tables are scanned without using joins

Comment: OK, this structure and query is good and classic. Is there any more optimal way to store and query data if it's very big? As I read here http://webbtechsolutions.com/2009/07/24/the-effects-of-distinct-in-a-sql-query/ DISTINCT makes query slow.